# An introduction to Lane-Riesenfeld algorithms

Tags: geometry, reference-request, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling

I am looking for a good introduction to Lane-Riesenfeld algorithms, which are a family of subdivision methods for generating uniform $B$-splines. Any suggestions? (The more "basic" the exposition the better.)

Comment: Try also http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these:

- Joe Warren, course notes on *Subdivision Methods for Geometric Design*.
  A copy is available at http://www.cs.rice.edu/~jwarren/research/ and at https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-01-winter/.
- Joe Warren and Henrik Weimer, book *Subdivision Methods for Geometric Design: A Constructive Approach*.
- Ron Goldman, book *Pyramid Algorithms, A Dynamic Programming Approach to Curves and Surfaces for Geometric Modeling*.
  ￼

Comment: Did the book by Warren grew out of the freely-available lecture notes you listed?

Comment: @user111691, yes, Warren says this in his page: "A monograph on subdivision written in 1994 that formed an initial draft for the subsequent book".